# Compare Strings ignoring accents in SQL

Tags: oracle

I would like to know if there is an easy way to compare two text values ignoring the accents and upper case. Im working with an Oracle database.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Specifying a Case-Insensitive or Accent-Insensitive Collation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch5lingsort.htm#i1008835)

> Append _AI to an Oracle Database collation name for an
>   accent-insensitive and case-insensitive collation.

So I could set, for example:

```
alter session set nls_sort=hungarian_ai;
```

But this above will affect only sorts and not the comparisons. You can set comparions to use the sort settings:

[NLS_COMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn10117.htm#REFRN10117)

> LINGUISTIC
>
> Comparisons for all SQL operations in the WHERE clause and in PL/SQL
>   blocks should use the linguistic sort specified in the NLS_SORT
>   parameter. To improve the performance, you can also define a
>   linguistic index on the column for which you want linguistic
>   comparisons.

```
alter session set nls_comp=linguistic;
```

With both of the above set:

```
SQL> select 'equals' as result from dual where 'ÁbCdEf' = 'aBcDéF';

RESULT
------
equals
```